# Why is normal contact force acting on a person in an elevator during a free fall 0?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, free-fall

Since normal contact force between two surfaces depends on molecular interaction between them, then why does its value change with the acceleration of the elevator?

Comment: It is called a free fall for a reason

Comment: So tell me the reason

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a free-falling body experience no force despite accelerating?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/196136/)

Comment: this is a duplicate @parshyaa please refer to the above link

Comment: no problem.  in future pls check for duplicates before posting

Comment: Yah sure i will keep it in mind

Comment: My question is still not answered in that link, in the link they are discussing a freely falling body , and  there is no contact force acting on a freely falling body and my question is  based on a  freely falling elevator in which a person is standing and before freely falling there was contact force acting on him but at the moment elevator started freely falling motion, contact force became zero how?

Comment: Voting to reopen. I agree with asker that the linked question does not provide a clear answer to this question.

Comment: @sammygerbil  how would i reopen my question, or is it possible

Comment: You could post a question on the Physics Meta Site explaining why your question is not a duplicate and asking why it remains closed. This should attract more Reopen Votes and is sometimes successful. See [modified closed question won't reopen](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10366)

Answer (score 0):

When acceleration changes, the equilibrium separation between molecules change and hence the reaction force changes.

Comment: How equilibrium separation between molecules changes with acceleration?

Comment: If the acceleration has changed, then the net force must have changed.  It's doubtful that gravity changed, so it must be the normal force between the object and the floor of the elevator that has changed.  In order for that to have happened, the intermolecular spacing must have changed.

Comment: Could you provide a link in reference to this , and how  change in acceleration of elevator changes the intermolecular spacing or norma force acting on a human standing inside the elevator