# Did we just misunderstand gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, gravity, acceleration

Einstein told us that a spring balance under free fall shows zero deflection and thus derived that  gravity is a curvature in the fabric of spacetime and all those stuffs.

Now let's assume we have a spring balance in **gravity-free space** (though there is a gravitational force between me and the balance) as shown below. If we somehow apply a *horizontal force* on the hook or pan using my fingers and with no opposing force on the spring, it starts accelerating in the direction of the force. *Will the pointer show any deflection ?*
[image]

No, and to get any deflection we need to apply another force in the opposite direction so that it doesn't accelerate and the spring inside the balance gets stretched ¹.

So does it mean that all forces are pseudo forces like gravity or we just misunderstood gravity? Doesn't this experiment signify that all forces have some common feature?  Or am I wrong somewhere?

**1** : In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/583784/measurement-of-force-statics) question OP mentioned that when the other end of a spring balance is free, it shows zero deflection.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57228/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61899/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic the question and the links are completely different. I am talking about the similarities between forces with an experiment.

Answer (score 2):

If we apply an unbalanced force to the spring balance and another unbalanced force to the mass attached to it so that both spring balance and mass have the same acceleration then the spring balance will not show any deflection.

But if we apply an unbalanced force to the spring balance and *no* external force to the mass attached to it then the length of the spring in the spring balance will change and the spring balance will show a deflection.

> ... we need to apply another force in the opposite direction such that the spring inside the balance gets stretched

No, I don't think this is correct.

Comment: why do you think it is not correct ?

Comment: @Ankit Because the spring will be stretched if we apply an unbalanced force to the spring balance and *no* force to the attached mass. We do not need to apply a force to the attached mass in the opposite direction to stretch the spring (although if we do then the spring will be stretched even more).

Comment: I didn't assume a particle attached.

Answer (score 1):

> If we apply a force on the pan using my fingers and with no opposing force, it starts accelerating in the direction of the force. Will the pointer show any deflection?

Yes. In fact, the pointer will show a deflection which is proportional to the force applied. The exact deflection depends on the mass of the pan, the spring, and the body of the spring balance. The more massive the body and the less massive the pan and the spring the greater the fraction of the force will be detected. What matters is how much the spring stretches, and by accelerating the pan it will stretch some.

See the free body diagrams below. The circle is the body of the scale, mass $M$, and the rectangle is the pan, mass $m$. The spring has a tension $\vec T$ and is assumed to have negligible mass. An external force $\vec f$ is applied to the pan and the scenario is analyzed from a reference frame which is accelerating at $-\vec g$. The inertial forces are parallel, and the tension forces are anti parallel. No other special directions are assumed.

[image: Free body diagrams]

After any initial transients die out the steady state is when the body and the pan have equal acceleration $\vec a$. Writing Newton’s 2nd law for the body and the pan gives $$ M \vec g -\vec T= M \vec a$$ $$m\vec g +\vec T +\vec f=m\vec a$$ Solving these for $\vec a$ and $\vec T$ gives $$\vec a= \frac{\vec f}{M+m}+\vec g$$ $$\vec T=-\frac{M}{M+m} \vec f$$

Note that the reading on the scale, $\vec T$, is proportional to $\vec f$ but does not depend on $\vec g$. So regardless of the acceleration of the reference frame (including $-\vec g=0$) the steady state reading on the scale depends only on the force applied.

Note also that the form of the inertial force is the same as the form of a uniform gravitational force. So the same conclusions apply to a Newtonian inertial frame in the presence of a gravitational field. The reading on the scale is independent of gravity.

Comment: so during free fall does it also show deflection ?

Comment: I have added some points to make my question clear.

Comment: @Ankit no, during free fall there is no deflection

Comment: so why is there a difference when the force is applied horizontally ?

Comment: @Ankit It has nothing to do with the direction of the force. It has to do with real forces vs fictitious/gravitational forces. I will add some details, but tomorrow

Comment: I will be waiting for your edit. **It has to do with real forces vs fictitious/gravitational forces**. BTW I was trying to prove that gravity is different from other forces i.e. it is fictious without assuming it to be.

Comment: During free fall, equal force is applied to all particles of the entire balance, which is why there is no deflection. When you apply a force *only* to the pan, there will be a deflection in the pointer.

Comment: @Ankit done. Hope it helps

Comment: Where did you find this pan from?

Comment: @Buraian I don't understand your question. What are you asking?

Comment: The question and this answer seem to mention a pan, however, there seemed to be no pan in the picture of the question. Now, OP has edited out the part about pan completely. You may want to consider that in your answer.

Comment: @Ankit it is expressly against the site rules to edit a question in a manner which makes previously received valid answers suddenly invalid. Please revert the edit which removed mention of the pan

Comment: @Dale it was a huge mistake if mine. I had imagined it the way I pictured. Sorry for your inconveniences. Literally sorry...

Comment: @Dale when Buraian mentioned about the pan in the comment then I noticed it.

Comment: @Ankit no problem, just please either add the pan back into the question or revert to a previous version where the pan was still referenced

Comment: @Dale but I never imagined this question with a pan. Then how can I change my doubt. I literally apologize for this mistake but I can't revert the edit since the pan was never a part of my imagination.

Comment: @Ankit it doesn't matter if it was part of your imagination or not. It was part of the question that you actually wrote. Once you receive answers to a question you are not allowed to make modifications to the question that invalidate the answer. You must revert this

Comment: @Ankit see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4147/should-we-disallow-vast-self-editing-of-a-question-completely-changing-its-me/4148#4148 of course, this is fairly minor about a pan vs. a hook, but it confused Buraian and I am not going to re-draw my free body diagrams at this point. I drew my diagrams and wrote the text in response to your question at the time as it was written. Anyway, I went ahead and proposed a minor edit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, it is the same as to apply a force on a massive spring. It will deflect according to Hooke's law while the force is there. And it will have an acceleration $a = \frac{F}{m}$.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the spring balance will show deflection.

You can think of it like this:

When you start applying force at one end of the spring balance then due to the [principal of locality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_locality) (whic means that any force will affect only it's immediate surrounding) only the nearest particle will accelerate. But since the the spring is made up of particles linked via intermolecular forces therefore this force will propagate through the medium of the spring (at the speed of sound) and rest of the spring will start gaining velocity too. But before each particle starts applying force on the next particle it would have moved a bit ahead of its original position (with respect to the rest of the particles). **This will lead to the expansion of the material of spring balance.**

---

**Aside**

From this you can easily see that if you accelerate the object above certain limit such that the intermolecular forces cannot match-up with then the material of the spring balance will first inelastically expand at certain point and then break-off.

Comment: @Ankit BTW, I just saw your comments on other answers and I think this post will be of help to you (here you will find both Newtonian picture as well as relativistic picture.): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/522637/249968