# What distinguished physical and pseudo-forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, inertial-frames, definition

Why are some forces are considered pseudo-forces while some are considered real or physical forces?

The definition of pseudo-forces that I know of is that they exist in noninertial reference frames but don't exist in inertial reference frames. Among other arguments is that they don't have an identifiable source.

However, a person certainly "feels" the pseudo-force such as in a car that is rounding a corner. How can it be proved, then, that the centrifugal force is not a real force? Why isn't what is "real" determined by the non-inertial reference frame?

Comment: Who are 'we'? Since you are asking this question, logically it does not include you yourself, which is a contradiction. Perhaps reformulate as: "What distinguishes physical and pseudo forces?"

Comment: @my2cts, you're right, I stated it as "we", because it is a generally accepted fact.

Comment: But you yourself don't know. There is no we except me.

Comment: Your question touches on an interesting point. If you reformulate it I may write an answer.

Comment: Because the inertial force can be more simply vewied and explained by the stationary frame. Kind of like earth being center point and travels in more complicated spiral graph pattern vs simpler ellipse.

Answer (score 13):

Real forces satisfy two fundamental requisites

1. They do not depend on the reference frame
2. They satisfy the third law of classical dynamics

Pseudoforces violate both requirements. Indeed, they appear only in some reference frames called, *non-inertial* in addition to real forces and they are added just to impose the validity of $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$ also in those reference frames. Secondly, all real forces always arise in pairs in the Newtonian formulation of mechanics: the body B exerts a force $\vec{F}$ on the body A and simultaneously the body A exerts the force $-\vec{F}$ on the body B.  If $\vec{F}$ is a pseudoforce acting on $A$, there is no $B$ and there is no $-\vec{F}$ acting on it.

(I stress that the notion of pseudoforce  is proper of Newton's formulation of classical mechanics. When passing to more general relativistic formulations, that distinction between forces and pseudoforces is not so sharp also because the language is different, and pseudoforces share the same *geometric* nature of the gravitational interaction: they are no longer "forces". So that it is difficult to directly compare the two scenarios.)

Comment: But why are these the requisites of what is a real force, specifically the first one?

Comment: That is just the formulation of classical mechanics invented by Newton. Why these choices? I do not know, the most honest answer should be because this formulation works very well in our every-day experience.  The first requisite is entangled with another deeper requisite known as the Galileian invariance of classical mechanics.

Comment: If  I know the functional form of a force acting on a body $F=F(t,x,v)$ in an inertial reference frame and I assume that $F$ takes the same values in every inertial reference frames, then  F=ma (used as a differential equation) produces the correct motion of the body in *every other* inertial reference frame.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is different in different reference frames. You would expect a universal force to be the same regardless of how you look at it.

Also, it is not easy to figure out the source of the force.* You feel like being pushed by something you can't identify, which appears to break with Newton's 3rd law. That is an indicator (although not certain proof) of it possibly being an effect we feel due to something else than forces.

Finally, you won't feel the centrifugal force if you close your eyes.** This indicates that it might be an illusion, a mind trick, due to the surroundings changing.

---

*<sup>Think centrifugal forces, Euler forces and the push you feel when standing in a braking bus, and then try to look for the source.</sup>

** <sup>Sure, in the turning car or braking bus you feel the seat underneath you pulling sideways or backwards. You feel the car door or bus rail slamming into you, pushing you. But try jumping just before the turn or the braking - you won't feel anything and with your eyes closed you won't notice any changes at all. Not until you touch something again, that is.</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119664/discussion-on-answer-by-steeven-what-distinguished-physical-and-pseudo-forces).

Answer (score 3):

This is a comment really.

Thinking of Newoton's force, F=ma as really **F**=d**p**/dt where **p** is the momentum vector gives the perspective where what is called a fictitious force  and a force are the same thing. It also makes momentum important and makes force liable to the conservation of momentum law. This perspective leads naturally to the use of the term "force"  in particle physics, interpreting Feynman diagrams, where there is a d**p**/dt at the vertices. It is the first order exchanges of gauge bosons that characterizes the "forces" of the standard model into electromagnetic , strong and weak.

Answer (score 2):

When you spin the ball attached to a string as you stated, what we call centrifugal force arises from the ball's inertial tendency to move away in a straight line per Newton's first law of motion. The string provides the centripetal force that keeps the ball from doing so. So we see the centrifugal and centripetal forces as resulting from the ball's inertial resistance to a change in acceleration rather than as direct forces alone.

Answer (score 2):

A pseudoforce indicates a force that would be absent in a different reference frame. A simple example is a linearly accelerated frame. If you weigh yourself in an accelerating elevator, your weight will deviate from its value in Earth frame. The spring inside the scale obeys Hooke's law, F=kx, tells you that x and thus the force exerted on it is different upon acceleration. This is a real force change, not a mathematical device. Why do we call this a pseudo force? Because we know that there is a simpler reference frame in which it is absent. By this reasoning gravity itself can be considered a pseudoforce. The simpler frame then is free fall.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo forces aren't physical forces because *we, humans* introduced them in order for Newton's 2nd law to work properly in non-inertial frame of references. Basically it's mathematical correctional term,very similar to cosmological constant introduced by Einstein in general relativity equations (if you know/heard of about that constant).  For more details, you can check my other answer at : [If an object is free falling under gravity, then where is the pseudo force applied?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/614067/if-an-object-is-free-falling-under-gravity-then-where-is-the-pseudo-force-appli)

Real forces like gravity, are *'real'* because we see and are influenced by the effects like by gravity. So much so, that our evolution is based on to counter gravity of our earth and thrive on land.

Note : cosmological constant and pseudo forces are not related or similar things. They are merely mathematical  correctional terms in their respective theories in order for theory to work properly.

Comment: Which part of physics is 'merely mathematical correction's and which part isn't? Which part of physics was _not_ introduced by us humans?

Comment: But they are for explaining real world stuff, not some mathematical fantasy.

Comment: @my2cts Also, where can you feel the pseudo force? It is not a fundamental force or something arising from fundamental forces' interaction. Its the definition of the pseudo force that is a mathematical correctional term

Comment: Bring a scale into an elevator and weigh yourself on it. Set the elevator in motion and look at the scale. The pseudoforce is the weight deviation from your reference weight.

Comment: @my2cts so according to you, if you can see real effects of pseudo force, then why it is called 'pseudo'. Classify them as real? Why not?

Comment: @my2cts What is real here is the pseudo-*effect*. But the pseudo-force is not a real force. It is, as Kshitij mentions, an invention made to make Newton's laws hold true within non-inertial frames. Or you could say that it is an invention made in order to explain our experience of pseudo-effects. Whether that qualifies as "real" is probably more of a philosophical or linguistic question but it is no doubt different from our usual idea of real forces.

Comment: @my2cts The reason the scale in the elevator shows a signal is due to the inertia from its carried load (and from itself) which is resisting the upwards acceleration. If anything, it is a normal force from this load which is pushing down on the scale and causing the display to react. The pseudo-force does not come into the picture before you try to explain from within the accelerating frame (from the elevator perspective) why you aren't accelerating inspite of being pushed upwards.

Comment: @Steeven exactly well answered

Comment: @Steeven I am not familiar with the concept of "pseudo_effect". Let's get our feet back on the ground. Assume the scale is based on a simple spring. As the lift accelerates wrt Earth frame, x changes. Plain old 17th century Hooke's law, F=kx, then tells me that there the force changes. This is a real force change, not a mathematical fantasy. Why do we interpret this as a pseudo force? Because we know that it is due to the acceleration of the lift, not an increase in gravity. We know there is a simpler reference frame in which it is absent.

Comment: By this reasoning gravity itself is a pseudoforce. The simpler frame then is free fall.

Comment: @my2cts yes gravity is 'considered' pseudo force because it unlike other fundamental forces' which exchange force particles to 'conduct' force, gravity according to general relativity, gravity is curvature of spacetime. So if new particle for gravity is not discovered, gravity would be pseudo force. But according to classical mechanics point of view, gravity is as real like other force fields

Comment: @my2cts Sorry, I didn't mean pseudo-effect, I meant centrifugal effect. That or Euler effect is the term I usually use. The spring in your example indeed compresses. The spring force increases. Agreed. But then you say "Why do we interpret this as a pseudo force?" - we don't. The spring force is a spring force. The pseudo force is something else - in this scenario it is the force which pushes down the scale and in turn pushes down the spring. The spring force is the reaction to this. I'm not sure if we are disagreeing about this?

Comment: @KshitijKumar I stated "**by this reasoning** gravity qualifies as a pseudo force". No lecture on GRT needed.

Comment: @Steeven The spring **measures** a force. A scale is a **measurement** device. It should have been clear that I was talking about the force it **measures**.

Answer (score 1):

*(This is a simplistic answer,that may be loose in language, and not universal. But may help a lot)*

Newtonian mechanics is primarily formulated (in a simplostic sense) for inertial frames.

In a non-inertial (non relativistic) reference frame, the frame itself inherently incorporates its own acceleration/rotation. But you don't see it, really. When you walk on the rotating earth, or corner in a car, you feel some things but you don't necessarily directly perceive with your senses the *non-inertial nature of your own reference frame*.

So the effects you do perceive - that the car door pushes you inward, or the cars motion seems to throw you outward, or the non Newtonian precision measurement on a rotating Earth - in a way,the pseudo forces are manifestations, or (misleading!) perceptions, that either account for or offset the less easily perceived non Newtonian aspect of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

> Why are some forces considered pseudo-forces while some are considered real or physical forces?

There are a variety of theoretical distinctions as listed in the other answers. However, since physics is an experimental science I prefer the practical/operational distinction:

Real forces can be detected with accelerometers and pseudo forces cannot.

> However, a person certainly "feels" the pseudo-force such as in a car that is rounding a corner. How can it be proved, then, that the centrifugal force is not a real force?

Actually, this is incorrect. Removing all of the complicated neural processing and psychology, just stick with accelerometers as indicators of what is actually “felt”.

When you are in a car rounding a corner your accelerometer reads an inward acceleration. Thus the only force that is actually felt is the centripetal force. The centrifugal force is not detected. If it were then the accelerometer would read 0. So both the direction and the magnitude of the accelerometer reading contradict the claim that the centrifugal force is a real force that is “felt”.

Comment: I think in actual practice, like engineering with accelerometers it is completely opposite actually. It won't detect gravity/free fall acceleration but will detect the said centrifugal forces, haha.

Comment: @marshal craft if you have a smartphone then you can simply do the experiment and see. Turn on your accelerometer app and have a friend drive while you look at the accelerometer. When you turn left the real force is left and the centrifugal force is right. So a left reading is real force only, a right reading is centrifugal only, and a zero reading is both. You will find it reads the real force only, as I said

Comment: Don't need to, I've worked with lis3 mems accel from stm, they are virtually the same ones employed, except they don't have mems gyro. The idea is, when in free fall its accel at 9.8 m/s^2 as we all know yet the mems will read zero. Additionally when they are stationary they will read a default accel of 9.8 m/s^2, they are usually trimmed to zero this out, via software.

Comment: @marshal craft the centrifugal force is the same way. In a rotating reference frame in free fall the accelerometer reads 0 even if it is accelerating outward by the centrifugal force. It does not detect the centrifugal force. If it is not in free fall, but rounding the bend, then it will sense only the centripetal force. It does not detect the centrifugal force. Given your experience with them, you really do need to do the experiment if you believe otherwise. My statements are demonstrably correct.

Comment: But it is true that it would not read the ficticous force i think.

Comment: @marshal craft yes, that is what I said. The fictitious centrifugal force is not detected. Only the real centripetal force is detected.

Comment: You are incorrect in that gravitational force is not distinguishable. Which was the basis of my original comments.

Comment: If you were in an elliptical orbit your phone, the lis3 and any force detecting accel would be useless and read zero. Even though your acceleration is quite real and non inertial referenced. Technically there would be micro tidal forces which could possibly be used. But no device uses this today. Instead stars and constant checking are used.

Comment: The new York times didn't care about godard's experience or thoughts when they said a rocket wouldn't work in space. 60 years later they offered an apology when experimental evidence, sputnik, showed them they were wrong.

Comment: @marshall craft you yourself said “when in free fall its accel at 9.8 m/s^2 as we all know yet the mems will read zero”. In free fall it is acted on by gravity (and only by gravity) yet the reading is zero. Therefore an accelerometer does not detect gravity. Furthermore, (without trimming) when it is at rest on a table subject the detected acceleration is 9.8 m/s^2 upwards! It is subject to an upward normal force and a downward gravitational force, and it detects only the upward normal force. The gravitational force is most emphatically not detected by an accelerometer.

Comment: @marshall craft my awareness is not based on iPhone apps. That was just a suggestion to help you figure this out. Accelerometers do not detect gravity and they also do not detect fictitious forces. This is experimental fact. You yourself even cited the correct facts and somehow misunderstood your own evidence. In free fall there is gravity but accelerometer reads 0, therefore accelerometer does not detect the acceleration due to gravity. If a device reads 0 when a thing is present then the device does not detect that thing. Accelerometers do not detect gravity by your own data

Answer (score 1):

In Newtonian physics, force is equal to the rate of change of momentum. In Lagrangian mechanics, we assert a function of position and velocity that governs the physics called the 'Lagrangian', and then 'force' is the partial derivative of the Langrangian with respect to position, and 'momentum' the partial derivative with respect to velocity. It looks a bit like:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}$ where $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=F$ and $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}=mv$

But Lagrangian mechanics allows positions $x$ to be expressed in non-inertial and curved coordinate systems (called 'generalised coordinates'), in which the relationship of the partial derivative to velocities in the flat, inertial coordinate system involves some extra terms. In an inertial reference frame (and assuming constant mass), these extra terms disappear and you just differentiate velocity to get acceleration (i.e. $F = ma$). In non-inertial or curved coordinates, you get extra terms on the right hand side, because you're differentiating with respect to something that itself varies. The trick with 'inertial forces' is just to transfer these extra terms over to the left hand side and call them part of the force. We're used to the form of the force being arbitrary, more so than the formula for acceleration.

Newtonian physics asserts as a postulate the existence of a set of inertial reference frames where these curvy extra terms vanish. It's not the only viewpoint on the matter, though.

In General Relativity, we allow much more freedom with regard to coordinate systems. If we consider a rock spinning in a static universe full of distant stars, Mach's principle suggests that this should be equivalent to a static rock in a universe with the distant stars spinning around it. And indeed, General Relativity predicts that there should be a gravitomagnetic force (a component of gravity analogous to the magnetic force in electromagnetism) that arises when there is a *flow* or *current* of mass, and in the case of the spinning universe turns out to match the centrifugal force. (See [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258665274_The_Machian_Origin_of_the_Centrifugal_Force).) Thus, the supposedly fictitious centrifugal force is just the gravitational force exerted by a spinning universe, and not fictitious at all! (Or at least, no more fictitious than gravity.)

In a sense, General Relativity pulls the same trick in reverse - it transfers all the forces over to the right-hand side of the equation and calls them curvature, leaving no 'real' forces. All particles follow free-fall paths through curved spacetime, and all forces are just aspects of curvature.

Of course, that doesn't apply in Newtonian mechanics, that asserts a simple inverse-square law for gravity, and a God-given set of inertial frames. Forces that can't be made to vanish and remain in the inertial frames are classified as 'real'.

Comment: It is not correct to say that in GR there are no real forces. Only gravity is treated as curvature of spacetime and thus no longer a force, in the traditional sense. All other forces, in particular elecromagnetic forces are real forces which "force" bodies to follow non-geodesics paths. These non-geodesics paths are described as "accelerated" and thus we recover the usual $F= dp/d\tau$ written covariantly

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo forces don't "exist" in a non inertial frame of reference either, they don't exist at all. What they are, is a consequence of the acceleration of the frame itself.

When an inertial frame of reference turns non-inertial --by gaining some acceleration. The effect of this acceleration would be felt by all bodies present inside the frame of reference, and this "feeling" is basically called a "Pseudo Force" for our mathematical convenience.

For example, in a downward accelerating Elevator,  observed from a far away and inertial frame of reference, there is no force other than gravity that would be applied to the passenger inside.

However, there is a funny feeling inside the stomach indicating that you, the passenger, is feeling a push upwards (when the situation is observed from (a non-inertial frame of reference) inside the lift).

This "feeling" isn't an actual force but simply the effect of the elevator (aka the frame of reference) accelerating downwards. But for our Mathematical and somewhat psychological ease we call it 'experiencing an upward pseudo force', this makes it easier to relate to and conveniently converts the frame into an inertial one, thus keeping Newton's equations just as applicable here. It's a mathematical trick, basically.